# Scrapy XPATH For-Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, xpath, scrapy

I am setting up my first Scrapy Spider and I'm having some difficulty using Xpath Selector.

The url which I'm trying to scrape data from is:

https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/

The website contains 9 pages and each page contains several 'boxes' or 'containers' for each company's name.

I'm trying to extract:

- Name
- Address
- Phone
- Email

[Box's schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU8G0.png)

If I a run the following code in the **Scrapy Shell**, I extract data correctly:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-11"]//p//text()').extract() #Names
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-2 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract() #Phones
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-4 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract() #Addresses
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-3 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract() #Emails
```

Also, if I run the following loop for each box, it returns 10 records (number of boxes in page 1):

[Scrapy Shell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0irbz.png)

```
for box in response.xpath('//div[@class="w-100 padding-15 "]'):
    print(1)
```

But, when I run the following I don't scrape any data:

*(In this case I use Relative Xpath)*

```
import scrapy
from NewContacts_Crawler.items import NewContactItem

class XubioContadoresSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "XubioContadores"
    start_urls = [
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=1',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=2',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=3',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=4',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=5',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=6',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=7',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=8',
        'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag=9',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = NewContactItem()

        for box in response.xpath('//div[@class="w-100 padding-15 "]'):

            name = box.response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-11"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            phone = box.response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-2 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            address = box.response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-4 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            email = box.response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-3 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            
            items['name'] = name
            items['phone'] = phone
            items['address'] = address
            items['email'] = email

            yield items
```

I use Scrapy's Xpath code as example:

```
import scrapy


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.xpath('.//div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').extract()
            }

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

So, I think that both parts of the loop work fine separately. But, I cannot identify where the problem in my code is.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see how many time it execute loop `for box ..` . Next I would check this relative path - maybe elements are NOT in `'//div[@class="w-100 padding-15 "]'` and then relative path `'.//div[@class="col-11"]//p//text()'` may search in wrong plase. And last - I don't know why you use `box.response.xpath` instead of `box.xpath`

Comment: BTW: you could use `for`-loop to generate links in `start_urls = [ ... ]`

Comment: I think I see one big mistake. You should create `items = NewContactItem()` inside `for`-loop - to have new `items` for new data. I'm not sure if it will work if you will use always  the same instance. It may change data in one instance and gives only one result.

Comment: did you check if it gives some error message - because I get error which confirms that it has to be `box.xpath` instead of `box.response.xpath`

Answer (score 0):

`Scrapy` displays many information when you run it in console/terminal and you should check what you get in messages because I get error message

```
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 15, in parse
    name = box.response.xpath('.//div[@class="col-11"]//p//text()').extract_first()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

which shows that it has to be `box.xpath` instead of `box.response.xpath`

---

Minimal working code.

It gives me file `CSV` with 87 items.

You can put all code in one file and run `python script.py` without creating `project`

```
import scrapy

class XubioContadoresSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "XubioContadores"

    start_urls = [
        f'https://socios.xubio.com/ar/contadores/?pag={i}' for i in range(1, 10)
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        
        for box in response.xpath('//div[@class="w-100 padding-15 "]'):

            name = box.xpath('.//div[@class="col-11"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            phone = box.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-2 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            address = box.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-4 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()
            email = box.xpath('.//div[@class="col-md-3 col-12 h-60"]//p//text()').extract_first()

            item = dict()
            
            item['name'] = name
            item['phone'] = phone
            item['address'] = address
            item['email'] = email

            yield item
            
# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(XubioContadoresSpider)
c.start()
```